# ¿Cómo invocar una ventana desde un botón usando wxGlade?

Tags: python-3.x, poo, eventos, wxpython

Necesito que al presionar un botón, el evento asociado a éste, genere otra ventana, sin embargo no he podido encontrar cómo asociar esto en wxglade.
De manera predeterminada wxglade genera la ventana principal (donde está el botón) y la ventana hija (la que aparece al presionar el botón) como objetos de diferente clase, yo les he puesto Nivel1 y Nivel2 respectivamente, sin embargo no sé como relacionar las funciones que tengo como eventos a la ventana Nivel2.
Las funciones asignadas a los diferentes botones son:click1,click2,revisar y aprobar

```
import wx

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class Nivel1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel1.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "boton1")
        self.button_2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "boton2")
        self.checkbox_1 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "revisado")
        self.checkbox_2 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "aprobado")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click1, self.button_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click2, self.button_2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.revisar, self.checkbox_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.aprobar, self.checkbox_2)
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel1.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel1.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 2, 2)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.checkbox_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.checkbox_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def click1(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'click1' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

    def click2(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'click2' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

    def revisar(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'revisar' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

    def aprobar(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'aprobar' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

# end of class Nivel1

class Nivel2(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel2.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel2.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_2")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel2.__do_layout
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Soy la ventana hija!")
        label_1.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        sizer_2.Add(label_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

# end of class Nivel2

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame1 = Nivel1(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame1)
        self.frame1.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abrir la ventana hija al pulsar el botón solo requiere que la instancies y llamar a su método `Show` desde el método enlazado al evento correspondiente (click en botón).

Te dejo como extra, por si lo necesitas, la implementación de un método (`make_modal`) que permite que tu nueva ventana tenga un comportamiento similar a un diálogo modal (deshabilite la ventana principal mientras la secundaria esté abierta, lo cual impide que se pueda crear una nueva ventana secundaria por ejemplo).

```
import wx

# begin wxGlade: dependencies
# end wxGlade

# begin wxGlade: extracode
# end wxGlade


class Nivel1(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel1.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "boton1")
        self.button_2 = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "boton2")
        self.checkbox_1 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "revisado")
        self.checkbox_2 = wx.CheckBox(self, wx.ID_ANY, "aprobado")

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click1, self.button_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.click2, self.button_2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.revisar, self.checkbox_1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CHECKBOX, self.aprobar, self.checkbox_2)
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel1.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_1")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel1.__do_layout
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer_1 = wx.GridSizer(2, 2, 2, 2)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.button_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.checkbox_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        grid_sizer_1.Add(self.checkbox_2, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        sizer_1.Add(grid_sizer_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def click1(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        child_frame = Nivel2(self)
        child_frame.make_modal(True)
        child_frame.Show()

    def click2(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'click2' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

    def revisar(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'revisar' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

    def aprobar(self, event):  # wxGlade: Nivel1.<event_handler>
        print("Event handler 'aprobar' not implemented!")
        event.Skip()

# end of class Nivel1

class Nivel2(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel2.__init__
        kwds["style"] = kwds.get("style", 0) | wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.SetSize((400, 300))

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def __set_properties(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel2.__set_properties
        self.SetTitle("frame_2")
        # end wxGlade

    def __do_layout(self):
        # begin wxGlade: Nivel2.__do_layout
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        label_1 = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Soy la ventana hija!")
        label_1.SetFont(wx.Font(20, wx.FONTFAMILY_DEFAULT, wx.FONTSTYLE_NORMAL, wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL, 0, ""))
        sizer_2.Add(label_1, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        self.Layout()
        # end wxGlade

    def make_modal(self, modal=True):
        if modal and not hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
            self._disabler = wx.WindowDisabler(self)
        elif not modal and hasattr(self, '_disabler'):
            del self._disabler

# end of class Nivel2

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame1 = Nivel1(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame1)
        self.frame1.Show()
        return True

# end of class MyApp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: me gustaría preguntarte: para cualquier nivel de ventana dentro de ventana se realiza de la misma manera? si conoces de algún libro o documentación sobre el tema y la compartes conmigo estaría fantástico, por todas partes he buscado en vano.
Muchas gracias por la solución!